# Error in displaying the results. Is the foreign key guilty?

Tags: hibernate

I have a problem in my  query.
I get the error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: idprovider of: sakila.entity.Order [from sakila.entity.Order c where c.idprovider like '2%']
```

and the method with the query is:

```
private void runQueryBasedOnIdProvider(){
    executeHQLQuery("from Order c where c.idprovider like '" + idProviderTextField.getText() + "%'" );

}
```

where `idprovider` is the foreign key in the table `Order`.

I want my program to display all orders made to a provider.

You can find the code [here](http://ideone.com/gC3IV). Sorry for putting the code there, but I am new here and I couldn't put it here.

I used the following terms: comanda and furnizor in the code and they mean order and provider.

I can't figure out for myself how to solve the problem and I want to thank you a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

HQL queries aren't expressed in terms of tables and columns, but in terms of entities and their persistent fields/properties and associations. The above query is valid only if the `Order` entity has a persistent field/property named `idprovider`.

It probably has a toOne association to the `Provider` entity, and the query should thus be

```
from Order o where o.provider.id like '2%'
```

But this is only a guess, since you didn't provide the code and mapping of the `Order` entity.

Learn how HQL works by reading [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).

Comment: I provided the code and mapping and maybe you can figure out why it isn't working. Thank you a lot for helping me!